# asynchronous validation of gwt "EditTextCell"

Tags: validation, gwt, asynchronous, datagrid, edit

I need to reproduce this behavior in a GWT dataGrid composed of "EditTextCell" Columns.

1- I'm in editing mode in Cell 1
2- WHEN "ENTER" THEN validate launch an asyncroneous Service to validate the cell
3- if (Not Valid) then keep editing mode and focus on current cell
4- else go to the next cell in EDIT mode.

Thank you :)